# The text length cannot exceed the limit 50

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to import a Watson conversation app to a LUIS app, I have already converted the json to its equivalent in LUIS converting all Watson entities into Lists with synonyms, but when I try to import it to LUIS I get the following error:

```
The text length cannot exceed the limit 50
```

What's the cause of this and how can I fix it? It may be related to the limit of 50 explicit lists detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries), if that's the case what exactly is a explicit list? I couldn't find any documentation related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dina mentioned above please check if the entity name or the list normalized value or the list value synonym is more than 50 characters. And you can try after fixing this. And regarding your second question: you can find more information about [explicit list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-patterns#explicit-lists). Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 4):

The entity name or the list normalized value or the list value synonym is more than 50 char.